# Reserve leftmost space/desktop for terminal in OSX

Tags: macos, mission-control

In OSX, is there a way to make a particular application always occupy the left-most "space" when I make it fullscreen? I want to always have iTerm2 on the far left. Currently every time I hit fullscreen on the iTerm2 window I have to manually move it to the left.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it can't be done with fullscreen - or I've never found a way, so would be happy to learn something new;-)

I've found fullscreen has a tendency to always add to the right of wherever you are. It also, even worse, then doesn't appear to register as a 'real' Space so you can't call it directly by  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>number</kbd>

My workaround has always been to use things maximised rather than fullscreen, then pin them to specific Spaces  - Right click in the Dock > Options > Assign to…

That then regains my ability to instantly transition to that specific Space & always know which App/s belong there.